# Remember windows size

Tags: windows, window

In Windows 7, if I drag a window edge vertically to extend the window full screen (vertical wise) and then close the window and reopen it reverts back to the window size before extending it.

Is there anyway to get it to remember the full vertical size and restore it next time the application is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some applications (like firefox) keep track of their position and will move themselves back to where they were.

Windows doesn't do this for them.  However, there are [utilities](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/12/09/automatically-move-and-resize-windows/) that can do this for you automatically.